# Error message on booting up Ubuntu 14.04.2

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel, dmesg

After upgrading from kernel `linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic` to `linux-
image-3.13.0-51-generic`, I am getting this error message in `dmesg` on startup:

```
[ 6.352555] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 6.355708] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: version message write failed: ret = -5
[ 6.355712] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: hbm_start failed ret = -5
[ 6.355714] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: reset failed
[ 6.355716] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: link layer initialization failed.
[ 6.355717] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: init hw failure.
[ 6.355880] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: initialization failed.
```

What do I do to correct this?

Comment: I just noticed the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you able to log-in? If yes, try adding `blacklist mei_me` line to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.

If this doesn't work , add the following line to `modprobe.conf.local`:

`install mei /bin/true` and restart.

Comment: Yes I am able to log in and do all my stuff. But whenever I boot up my system the above error message is displayed.

Comment: Do I modify both the files simultaneously? Because I corrected the first modification and then did the second modification and it did not work.

Comment: I solved it in the following way.

1. Become root using `sudo --i` .Give your password. 
2. Then do `echo "blacklist mei_me" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`.
3. Then type `exit`. After that reboot.
4. On rebooting you might get an error `Error: Driver 'pcspkr' is already registered, aborting`.
5. Then again follow the steps 1-3 , with the modification in step 3 being `echo "blacklist pcspkr" > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

I have done the above steps in my system and it is running normally.